# Anchor tag with onclick and href='#' scrolls to top

Tags: javascript, html

I have an anchor tag

```
<a href="#" onclick="Register();" >Register</a>
```

If you don't have a href in you anchor, it can screw up some stuff, but I don't need to redirect, just call a js function. When this link is clicked however, the href="#" causes it to scroll the page to the top. How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel Browser Scroll Reset for Inline Onclick ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693978/cancel-browser-scroll-reset-for-inline-onclick)

Answer (score 13):

You can add a `return false;`, like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Register(); return false;">Register</a>
```

This prevents the default action of the anchor, which is to go to the hash, causing the scroll.

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Register(); ">Register</a>
```

javascript:void(0) will prevent the page from getting redirected and also will fix the issue where your page is getting scrolled on top due to href="#"